# Posting a Form from Site 'a' Login to Outlook

Tags: php, html, concrete5

http://tildencoil.artesiandesign.net/

This is the site which I am having a problem with. I am trying to post from the login hover menu in the top right to the outlook form linked from directly clicking on login. I can provide code if necessary, unless there is a simple way that the community knows of. If you need more information just ask. Thanks for any help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems there is no CSRF tokens (typical MS ;p) you can POST the values directly to the owaauth.dll  (untested as do not have login).

```
<form action="https://smtp2.tilden-coil.com/owa/auth/owaauth.dll" method="POST">

<input type="hidden" name="destination" value="https://smtp2.tilden-coil.com/owa//">
<input type="hidden" name="flags" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="forcedownlevel" value="0">

<label for="username">User name:</label>
<input id="username" name="username" type="text"/>
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input id="password" name="password" type="password">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! That worked perfectly! and yes typical MS :P Thanks for making that really easy on me :D I appreciate your help!